# Using handlebars each helper to load images with alt tags

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, yaml

I am trying to use a handlebars each helper to load multiple images while also being able to include an **alt** tag for each image that is loaded.

I am using the each loop in a partial...

```
{{#each screenshots}}
    <img src="{{this}}" alt="">
{{/each}}
```

and then using that partial in a yml file...

```
screenshots:
  - /path_to_image1.png
  - /path_to_image2.png
  - /path_to_image3.png
  - /path_to_image4.png
  - /path_to_image5.png
```

This properly loads the images, the problem I'm having is being able to add an **alt** tag for each one of the images.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use dictionaries in your yaml file to represent each img. Giving each img a `src` and `alt` key.

[Here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/yaml/) you can find examples on using dictionaries in yaml files.